# Slow initial connection to database (php / mssql)

Tags: networking, web-server, performance, database, performance-monitoring

Our webserver and database server are on a local network and the webserver uses an IP address to connect to the database.

```
$con = new \PDO('sqlsrv:Server=10.200.2.1\sql2017;Database=dbname, $user, $pass);
$con->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The first page that calls this code will take about 4 seconds to run just the above code. Then I can refresh the page as often and for as long as I want and it will register this code as almost 0 ms.

But if I stop refreshing the page for about 1 or 2 minutes, then the first connection will take 4 seconds again.

All 50 queries I ran after the above code run fine with less then a milisecond per query in either case.

If I wait two minutes and access the website simultaneous from two seperate computers, both will take 4seconds.

It seems there is some sort of timeout after a minute or so and something has to be cached again. How can I find out what this is and possibly increase the timeout?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a reverse DNS issue maybe? Try adding a line for 10.200.2.1 with a hostname to your hosts file.

Comment: A very simple and effective solution. Connection time went from 4000+ too less then 20ms with the host file. If you add it as an answer I can award the credits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this relates to MSSQL doing a reverse lookup on 10.200.2.1 which is/was timing out.   By adding an appropriate entry to the hosts file this can resolve more-or-less instantly and fix the wait.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same or similar issue. I tried the host file solution, but it has made no difference. My first load is much more than 4 seconds though... more like 45 seconds, then every page loads almost instantly after including the initial page. Then if it sits for 60 seconds, i get the slow 45 second load all over again. I tried running all queries in the database and get fast results.

Strangely, if I run the website directly on the web server, it works without issue. Does that narrow it down to a network configuration issue?

Does anyone have any other thoughts/solutions? I'm using a .php pdo connection on windows server 2019, and sql server 2019 on a separate windows box.